# JOptionPane Playing Audio?

Tags: java

so i wanted to make 4 buttons and each play a url online mp3 depending on the button clicked but i've never worked with audio so i'm not really sure how :( i have the panel made i just dont understand playing the audo audio. thanks so much!

```
String[] buttons = { "Sound1", "Sound2", "Sound3", "Sound4" };

int b = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Pick your sound.", "Confirmation",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, 0, null, buttons, buttons[2]);

System.out.println(b);
```

---

```
    try { 
        java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".wav"); 
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url); 
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
        clip.open(audioIn); 
        clip.start(); 
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    new lol(); 
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JOptionPane and all to do with your not being sure how to play audio. So get rid of the JOptionPane code as it has nothing to do with your problem, and please show us what you have tried regarding just playing audio, and tell us what step you're stuck on. Surely you've Googled this and so have some idea what to do, right?

Comment: oh my god who cares lol just give me the code

Comment: Regarding, `"oh my god who cares lol just give me the code"` -- Listen, I care, and I'll tell you why. In order to figure out how to help, we have to know what you may be doing wrong or what misconceptions you may have on how to do this. This means your posting code **relevant** to your problem will help us immensely in figuring out how to help you. Also for future reference and to help make your experience here more pleasant, know that your demanding us to `"just give me the code"` will do little more than alienate and antagonize and may make some of us not want to help you.

Comment: and now you -1 this thread loool, holy, this site is more useless than therri shiavo's brain cells

Comment: Regarding, `"holy, this site is more useless than therri shiavo's brain cells"` -- You have two options here: 1) show us more of the code relevant to your problem and describe your problem in greater detail. Doing this will likely get you help quicker and **up-votes**, or 2) you can complain. I know what I'd do.

Comment: try {
          java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".wav");
          AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          clip.open(audioIn);
          clip.start();
       } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new lol();
    }

Comment: I've posted your code above as an edit to your question since comments can't really hold code, although I'm betting that the resource String was mangled by the site's formatting, and that perhaps you have a `*` in there? Please correct this by editing your question. Does your code compile? If it does and it runs, what does it do? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

`javax.sound` doesn't support MP3 by default. You need to install this plugin:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html

With the plugin, this should work:

```
AudioInputStream ais = ...
AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
Line l = AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, af));
(((SourceDataLine)l).open(af);
(((SourceDataLine)l).start();
```